# Why is it a noun phrase and not an adjective phrase? or is it both?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the sentences **"The boy is ten years old"** and **"the boy is happy"**.

"**Ten years old**" is a noun phrase, and "**happy**" is an adjective? why isn't **Ten years old** an adjective doesn't it also provide information about the boy similar to happy?

I feel like **Ten years old** functions like both adjective and noun phrase. Please clarify.

Comment: "The boy is ten years old" is like "The boy is **happy**" (adjective), not like "The boy is **my son**" (noun).

Answer (score 3):

*Ten years old* is an adjective phrase. Its main word (or head) is *old*, which is an adjective.

But it contains a noun phrase that modifies that adjective — *ten years*. It's a measure phrase that tells you **how** old he is. Other examples of noun phrases modifying adjectives include: *five meters wide*, *six hours long*, *five hours late*.

Comment: But the *exact* form changes depending on whether the adjectival phrase is "predicative" (after the noun) as in *The boy is **ten years old***, OR "attributively (before the noun) as in *He is a **[ten-year-old boy](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ten+year+old+boy%22)***. The hyphens might not *always* be there, but we always switch to singular for the unit of measurement there, such as a ***three meter plank.***

Comment: How can a noun phrase modify an adjective should it. Not be an adverb?

Comment: @Nikhilonly No, not necessarily. Adverbs are the most common type of modifier in adjective phrases, but not the only type.